# Not able to deploy geoserver.war through apache tomcat

Tags: geoserver, tomcat, deployment

When i try to upload the geoserver.war file through apache tomcat and then deploying by clicking on Deploy .....deployment failed

Screenshot[image: apache homepage]

Comment: error :This site can't be reached

Comment: look in the log file to see why?

Comment: and where i can find log file??

Comment: /var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out

Comment: sir as i m new to GIS ......so i dont understand what u r trying to say

Comment: please explain in detail

Comment: On your Windows installation the logs will be at something like C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\logs\

Comment: yes sir i got the file by name="catalina.2016-08-02"

Comment: what next i have to do??

Comment: Look at that file to see the error message

Comment: sir i have opened the file in notepad........but i can't find any error messages

Comment: sir i m waiting for ur reply

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor. Also be aware that ["**We are not a GIS Software Support Site**. We encourage you to seek official routes for support for specific issues you may have."](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe that is a problem of the filesize of the WAR file of geoserver.

At default tomcat only accepts 50MB in the WAR files to upload, open with notepad the file: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\manager\WEB-INF\web.xml`

and find the lines with the text: `<max-file-size>` and `<max-request-size>`.

Increase that value, for example:

```
<max-file-size>92428800</max-file-size>
<max-request-size>92428800</max-request-size>
```

Restart tomcat and try again.

Regards...