# Deploy GeoServer inside Apache Tomcat in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: geoserver, tomcat, deployment, google-cloud

I am currently working on a little GIS web app. I have deployed Apache Tomcat on [Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/)

[image]

and I want to install GeoServer on it. I have downloaded the web archive of GeoServer 2.16 but when I want to deploy it on Tomcat, I have an error as you can see below

[image]

From this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/204495/not-able-to-deploy-geoserver-war-through-apache-tomcat), it seems to be a file size error, as said "default tomcat only accepts 50MB in the WAR files to upload, and the web archive of GeoServer is 98.1 MB. So I need to change this"

Since my Tomcat is on the cloud, please how to change this constrains?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit the Tomcat `webapps/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml` file, change the section like

```
<multipart-config>
   <max-file-size>52428800</max-file-size>
   <max-request-size>52428800</max-request-size>
   <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
</multipart-config>
```

Updating the `<max-file-size>` and `<max-request-size>` sections to a value in the region of 104857600 bytes.